# Adding Properties into a List or Collection

Tags: c#, list, generics, func

I have come across a situation where I probably needed to add properties(of a class) in a list to invoke them manually(or you can say, I need to assign there values(setter)). That is why because, I don't even know which properties is to set the values, but they are decided at runtime. So far I am trying to find out the solution here and there but still I don't get any article that even hints me a work around for this purpose.
Here's what I want to do exactly (mentioned as comments)-

```
public class DemoClass
{
    IList<Properties> _listOfProps;
    private int _iFirstProperty;
    private string _iSecondProperty;

    public DemoClass()
    {
        _listOfProps = new List<Properties>();
    }


    public int FirstProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _iFirstProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            _iFirstProperty = value;
            // Here I want to add this property into the list.
            _listOfProps.Add(FirstProperty);
            RaisePropertyChanged("FirstProperty");
        }
    }

    public string SecondProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _iSecondProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            _iSecondProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SecondProperty");
        }
    }

    public void HandleChangedProperties()
    {
        foreach (var list in _listOfProps)
        {
            // Here I want to invoke the property. ie. sets the 'value' of this property.
            list.Invoke(value)
        }
    }
}
```

I know, I can use Func to add in the list like- but I can't go with this.

```
List<Func<int>> listOfFunc = new List<Func<int>>();
listOfFunc.Add(() => { return 0; }); // Adds using lambda expression
listOfFunc.Add(temp); // Adds as a delegate invoker

private int temp()
{
    return 0;
}
```

from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

> Properties can be used as if they are public data members, but they
>   are actually special methods called accessors.

if properties are internally methods, Why they can't be added as *List of Func<>* 

Also, if there's no way I can do that without using Reflection (by getting PropertyInfo list), why Microsoft hasn't designed this in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either keep a list of `PropertyInfo` values and later set the value of the properties using reflection, or you can keep a list of setter delegates (which effectively just forward the value to the real, hidden setter).

For example:

```
IList<Action<object>> listOfSetters;

listOfSetters.Add(o => this.FirstProperty = (int)o);

// and then:
listOfSetters[0](42); // FirstProperty = 42
```

Comment: This one works nice. But still I would like to know, Why Microsoft has not written this feature ?

Comment: @RohitPrakash: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "this feature". There are multiple ways to do what you want, each with different tradeoffs.

Comment: I mean I can add a funtion as a delegate invoker like **List<Func<bool>>** , but the same can't be done for a property list ? Using Action<object> doesn't referes what  Func<object> refers to.

Comment: The difference is that properties are not first class values, while delegates are. If you want a list of properties the way to represent those is `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: Thank Jon. I got it. Though I would still like to see this short writing syntax in C# future development.